# Deleting Array of Array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I would like your help removing records from an array using an array to define the records that need to be removed, please see the example below

**Array 1**

```
$exclusion = array("ABC-DEF","GHI-JKL");
```

**Array 2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => ABC-DEF
        [Stack] => Dev
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => KML-XWZ
            [Stack] => Test
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => GHI-JKL
            [Stack] => Mock
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [Name] => MNO-PQR
            [Stack] => String
        )
)
```

**Expected Output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => KML-XWZ
            [Stack] => Test
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => MNO-PQR
            [Stack] => String
        )
)
```

Comment: Please share your attempts and what they currently produce. We're here to help you fix issues with your existing code, but we're not here to write it all for you. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: I am rising this as request after several attempts not blindly

Comment: **Below is the code that i tried** `$exclusion = array("ABC-DEF","GHI-JKL");
foreach($arrays as $array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(in_array($value, $remove)) unset($array[$key]);
    }
}``

Comment: @Vino Please edit your question to include what you tried. Ideally, also include the actual output of your code. Be aware that in your case you want to unset elements from `$arrays`, not `$array`

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing, and surely you can try looping through the $target array and set a condition to unset elements using the [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) php function for checking each item against the $excusion array you have.